# What is the purposes of these sugars?

Tags: cell-biology, sugar, blood-sugar

What is the function of $\alpha$-D-glucofuranose and $\beta$-D-glucofuranose?

Are they both converted into energy? Or are they just different variations with no particular difference in function?

I tried searching but found nothing on the web except chemical structures.

Comment: What do you mean by *purpose* or *function*?

Comment: You see, there are types of glucose. And I want to know what a-d-glucofuranose and b-d-glucofuranose does in the cell.

Comment: I think you can ask that without referring to *purpose* or *function*, as these imply that  someone designed it that way versus being sort of an organic chemistry curiosity about glucose.

Comment: Please provide some context and describe the results of your own research. Why do you want to know about these compounds? Where have you read about them? Do they occur in the certain foodstuffs — or have you just seen their names in a chemical classification of sugars, and have no idea whether or not they occur in nature? I find nothing on the web except chemical structures.

Comment: So whats the problem about this question?

Comment: What makes you think they're found in cells? There are lots of things that turn-up in a biochem. lab which aren't found in nature, but are used in synthesis. Or just held onto for future use.

Comment: So are these found in cells of living things or not? Im very confused just give me the answer "they arent found in living things"

Comment: As a new user to this site "for biology researchers, academics, and students" you seem not to understand how this site or science works. You are supposed to post about a biological problem that you have encountered, and if anyone knows the answer they provide it with evidence or links to support. As far as I can tell — you still haven't told us — you have discovered a classification of sugars somewhere, and because glucose is a natural sugar you have assumed all other chemicals of this category are. This is not so, and chemists traditionally synthesize and describe any compound possible...

Comment: ...You then ask us to tell you "they aren't found in living things", without understanding that we have no knowledge, evidence of other basis for saying that, so as scientists we cannot. The fact that we have never encountered them doesn't mean that some plant somewhere doesn't produce them. Chemists have synthesized thousands of compounds, so how should anyone here know which existe in nature (and why should we care)? We would assume that you would know something about them to go to the trouble of posting, but it seems not, or you are not going to tell us, so I suggest your post be removed.

Comment: Im sorry, im deleting this post.